# Find the number of positive integers such that logarithm of whose reciprocals to the base 10 has the characteristic $-2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Find the number of positive integers such that logarithm of whose reciprocals to the base 10 has the characteristic $-2$.

---

Let $x$ be a positive integer.
Now the characteristic of $\log_{10}(\frac{1}{x})$ is $-2$
I dont know how to solve further.How to count number of positive integers?Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you have the right definition of characteristic.  You need a floor or ceiling function somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your question, $log_{10} {1/x} = -2$

${1/x} = 10^{-2}$

$x = 100$

does this help?

Comment: No,this is not the answer.The answer is $90.$

Comment: @Vinod, can u explain how u got the answer.

Comment: I have just quoted the book's answer,i dont know how it came.

Comment: @vinod does the book meant number of such positive integers is $90$

Comment: Yes,number of such positive integers is $90$,@EkaveeraKumarSharma